# How to duplicate heads on a MacBook Pro

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I've been trying to copy unique player heads to look at and decorate my maps and homes with, but instead of getting the head of a player when I control+middle click, I get Steve's head. Is there any way to do this another way? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Cmd + Middle click

Answer (score 3):

According to a user named quartz in the comment section of a [related bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-68797), the way to copy a block including its NBT data is slightly different on a Mac. It is done via <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Pick Block</kbd> (default is Mousebutton 3), rather than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Pick Block</kbd>.

You can verify that this worked by mousing over the item in your hotbar. It should say "+NBT data" in purple.

Comment: Just curious how did you type the buttons?

Comment: @ModDL using html tags: `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`. I think it's explained under "Advanced Formatting help". Pro-Tip: [edit] the answer to see the unformatted version.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I actually just figured this out by accident!

-Tap CMD and PickBlock together quickly

If that doesn't work try this:

How to pick block + NBT (MAC)

1. Hold CMD + [PickBlockBind]
2. Release CMD & immediately hold it back down again
3. Block should copy the block and its NBT!

Answer (score -1):

The player head is unavailable in Survival minecraft. The only means to obtaining a specific player head is through commands. Player skulls have the nbt tag of `SkullOwner` which can be specified to get a particular player's skull.

Due to the fact that the SkullOwner is an NBT tag, it is possible to duplicate the head in creative by using the NBT pickblock function, which involves using pickblock whilst the Ctrl key (if on a Windows operating system) or The Cmd Key (if on an OSX operating system).

Using the website [Minecraft Custom Heads](http://heads.freshcoal.com/) it is possible to generate heads that are not someone's head.

Answer (score -2):

In creative if you already have 1 of the player head and you just want to duplicate it you should be able to simply use `<PickBlock>`. You can check your keybindings under Menu->Controls to find out what you have it bound to.

In creative you can use `<Left-Shift> + <PickBlock>` to copy NBT data as well but shouldn't been necessary with player heads.

Using the command `/give <YourName> minecraft:skull <qty> 3 {SkullOwner:"HeadYouWant"}` Where the 'qty' is the number of heads you want.

Comment: Killing a player will never drop their head. Ctrl + Shift + MiddleClick Does not copy NBT, and He is looking for the Mac Equiv.

Comment: @ModDL I updated the answer. Taken straight from minecraft wiki.